# summarizing two text files and make a new one in python

Tags: python

I have 2 text file like the following examples. I name one of them first(comma separated) and the other one second(tab separated).

`first`:

```
chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2
chr1,5310000,5960000,2,1,5,4
chr1,1580000,1180000,4,1,5,3
chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4
chr1,7680000,8300000,3,1,1,2
chr1,109220000,110070000,4,2,3,3
chr1,11060000,12070000,6,2,7,4

second:

AKAP8L  chr19   107180100   107650000   transcript
AKAP8L  chr19   15514130    15529799    transcript
AKIRIN2 chr6    88384790    88411927    transcript
AKIRIN2 chr6    88410228    88411243    transcript
AKT3    chr1    105002000   105010000   transcript
AKT3    chr1    243663021   244006886   transcript
AKT3    chr1    243665065   244013430   transcript
```

in the `first file` columns `2` and `3` are `start` and `end`. in the `second file` column `3` and `4` are start and end respectively. I want to make a new text file from both first and second files. 
in fact I want to select some rows from the file first if:

```
1- the 1st column in file first is equal to 2nd column in file second.
2- the 3rd column in the file second is greater than the the 2nd column in the file first and also smaller than the 3rd column in the file first.
3- the 4th column in the file second should be also greater than the the 2nd column in the file first and also smaller than the 3rd column in the file first.
```

in the new file I will add 2 new columns called `ID` and `count` and basically I will count the number of rows in the file second which have the above 3 conditions. for the ID I will use the 1st line of file second which matches to one of the lines in the file first.
in other word, I want to count the number of rows in the file second which match every row in the file first according to 3 above mentioned conditions.
the expected output for the example would look like the this:

```
chr19,107180000,107680000,1,1,5,4,AKAP8L, 1
chr1,105000000,105310000,2,1,3,2, AKT3, 1
```

in this expected output, the 1st 7 columns are from the file first anf the 8th column is ID (which is taken fro the file second) and the 9th column is the count (of the number of lines in the file second which match to these specific line in the file first).

I am trying to do that in python and wrote this code but it does not return what I am looking for.

```
first = open('first.csv', 'rb')
second = open('second.txt', 'rb')
first_file = []
for line in first:
    first_file.append(line.split(','))

second_file = []
for line2 in second:
    second_file.append(line.split())

count=0
final = []
for i in range(len(first_file)):
    for j in range(len(second_file)):
        first_row = first_file[i]
        second_row = second_file[j]
        first_col = first_row.split()
        second_col = second_row.split()
        if first_col[0] == second_col[1] and first_col[1] < second_col[2] < first_col[2] and first_col[1] < second_col[3] < first_col[2]
            count+=1
            final.append(first_col[i]+second_col[0]+count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the necessity `count` of count, because, as far as I can understand, it just seems like a row index. It's included in the below code as comments (just uncomment if you want to use `count`). In your `if` statement, you are comparing values as strings, not integers, so you must cast them to integers first. In the arguments for `append`, you are trying to concatenate single elements, which doesn't work. Simply wrap them around square brackets. Also, there's no need to open plaintext files as binary.

I used the `csv` module, which in my opinion simplifies it. Also, there's nothing wrong with the way you iterate over the data, but it's usually easier to use `for item in mylist` instead of `for i in range(len(mylist)): item = mylist[i]` Anyway, try this:

```
import csv

with open('first.csv', 'r') as firstfile, open('second.txt', 'r') as secondfile:
    first = list(csv.reader(firstfile))
    second = list(csv.reader(secondfile, delimiter='\t'))

final = []
#count = 0

for row1 in first:
    for row2 in second:
        if (row1[0] == row2[1] and int(row1[2]) > int(row2[2]) > int(row1[1])
                and int(row1[2]) > int(row2[3]) > int(row1[1])):
            final.append(row1 + [row2[0]])
            #count += 1
            #final.append(row1 + [row2[0]] + [count])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    outwriter.writerows(final)
```